# Structure : Instantiating types which have no dependencies

Tags: .net, structuremap

What is the best approach to solving the following:

In an application I am developing I have a class, ScheduleNotifer, which publishes messages to other interested classes within my applications or from plugin assemblies. The subscribers are decoupled from the ScheduleNotifer and so do not get instantiated via cstor injection or setter injection. Is it possible for StructureMap to automatically instantiate these classes without me having to call container.GetAllInstanceOf() from within ScheduleNotifier

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your comment clarifies things a bit.  Structuremap does not have anything similar to IStartable, so you would need to create a class that handles this.  This class, lets call it PluginStarter, would take an IEnumerable in its constructor and would handle the lifetime of these objects.

Comment: The ScheduleNotifier uses a MessageBroker to send the actual messages and the MessageBroker manages the subscriptions. What I'm really interested in knowing is if it's possible to scan a plugin dll and auto instantiate the subscribers within it. The subscribers have a dependency on the MessageBroker and register there interest in certain messages the ScheduleNotifer will be publishing. Some of these subscribers are really dumb and perform some simple logging to the db. No other classes in my app depends on them.

I've read that the CastleWindsor has an IStartable facility. Has SM something s